how to add a class to one button inside a menu based on php foreach?
i have a video site like youtube .
admin can add many categories with no limit .
these categories display on top of the site as a horizontal menu .
this is the code that display the categories :
<?php 
    foreach($pt->categories as $key => $category) {
        if (1) { 
?>
            <div class="swiper-slide">
            <a class="" 
                href="{{LINK videos/category/<?php echo $key?>}}" 
                data-load="?link1=videos&page=category&id=<?php echo $key?>">
<?php echo $category?></a>
            </div>
<?php 
        } 
    }
?>

by this code if i add "active" to class="" , all the buttons of the menu will has "active" .
what i need is :
each button has "active" class when it clicked .
example :
categories : CARS , SPORT , NEWS , KIDS .
buttons : CARS , SPORT , NEWS , KIDS .
clicking on SPORT button will open sport page, SPORT button must have
"active" class after clicked and CARS , NEWS , KIDS buttons dont have "active" class .
clicking on KIDS button will open kids page , KIDS button get "active" class and remove "active" class from SPORT button .

If you're looking to add the class when it's clicked, I don't think the php is relevant; please [edit] your question to include the rendered html and the javascript you have tried.

I think you will have to do this is javascript

in my post i did not ask to do it by php only !
i just explained how it works .
and i dont know javascript or php .

You didn't, but the php isn't particularly relevant here; the javascript will be working with the rendered html, so we really need to see that.

ok i will do , i will find it

i added a js code and hope this is the right code .
if not , i will ask the developer about the javascript that related to this menu .

No, the JS you just added doesn't do anything with clicking or classes.

i think : it is not has a js , because it is not a menu , it is just one code under foreach .
if i wrong i will ask the developer of the site script about this .

Is this a JS problem or a PHP problem?

If you want active class on the current URL's menu item, you need to identify it. I try to identify it by extracting the id from the query string, but maybe a better approach would be to extract the category. Is ajax used? how does a typical link to category SPORT look like, for example?
I also added a function to escape the html before outputting it, for security.
<?php

function esc_attr($str)
{
    return htmlspecialchars((string) $str, ENT_QUOTES);
}

// get id from request
$id = $_GET['id'] ?? null;

foreach ($pt->categories as $key => $category) {
    if (1) {
        $class = '';
        if ($key == $id) {
            $class = 'active';
        }
        ?>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <a class="<?php echo esc_attr($class); ?>" href="{{LINK videos/category/<?php echo esc_attr($key); ?>}}" data-load="?link1=videos&page=category&id=<?php echo esc_attr($key); ?>">
                <?php echo $category ?></a>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
}
?>

To sort by "active" first, I will do it using 2 passes. Not efficient but simple.
for ($mode = 0; $mode < 2; $mode++) {

    foreach ($pt->categories as $key => $category) {
        if (1) {
            $class = '';
            if ($key == $id) {
                $class = 'active';
            }

            if ($class == "active" && $mode == 1 || $class != "active" && $mode == 0) {
                continue;

            }
            ?>
            <div class="swiper-slide">
                <a class="<?php echo esc_attr($class); ?>" href="{{LINK videos/category/<?php echo esc_attr($key); ?>}}" data-load="?link1=videos&page=category&id=<?php echo esc_attr($key); ?>">
                    <?php echo $category ?></a>
            </div>
            <?php
        }
    }

}


how to load $category inside div id="related-videos-side" without reload the page ?
i mean : clicking on any category button loading the category data inside div #related-videos-side instead of open it in a new page .

at the same time the button take ACTIVE class within the data is inside the dive

are you asking how to use ajax?

yes .
this code : href="{{LINK videos/category/}}"
open the category in a full new page . i want to open it inside div id="related-videos-side" without reload the page . dont care for css and how it looks inside the div . i will design it i know css .

that depends really how he content of the LINK is arranged. does it have header and footer? anyway ajax is all about getting html or json from server and using it with javascript. learn more https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp

this code i found make the job but it make it slowly : $('.load_me').on('click', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
var page = $(this).attr('href');
$('#related-videos-side').load(page);
});
take a time until open the content in the div .
is it possible to improv it ?
